# Azure Notification Hubs with Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services

In order to use Azure Notification Hubs in my Cordova application,
i searched the web.

I could not find any solution that looks reliable to me. For example 
i found https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub
but the last commit was 2 years ago.

Iam familiar how to do it in Android using Java (native) but want to do the exact same thing now in cordova (simply subscribe to a hub and recieve pushes)

What is the current way to achieve my goal? Do you know any links or tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

This is more recent: https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/CordovaNotificationsArticle  but it does require Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 to install the Cordova tools if you don't have it.

Comment: The companion article is here: [Microsoft Azure : Push Notifications to Cordova Apps with Microsoft Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879353.aspx). See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2015/01/05/use-azure-to-send-push-notifications-to-visual-studio-cordova-apps.aspx